# How to add Delphi code to version control?

Tags: delphi, visual-sourcesafe

I want to add Delphi-4 code to VSS via the IDE. Is that possible?
How to do so?

I am working on enhancements for a code written in Delphi 4. The name of the folder is "testCheck".
I tried  saving the code directly into VSS by clicking

```
        workgroups\Add "testCheck" to version control
```

then i checked the VSS to see the latest versions.... I am unable to find the latest version.

Now when I go back to the IDE the "workgroups\Add "testCheck" to version control"
cannot be clicked.it has become unclickable.

Any idea of what the method is to save/ copy code from Delphi IDE to VSS?

Thanks and Regards
Vas

Comment: Delphi 4 and VSS? Did I just travel back in time? Can anyone hear me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [VssConneXion](http://www.epocalipse.com) to interface to VSS from Delphi 7. Not certain of their support for version 4. Although I'm running as fast as I can towards SVN currently.

Comment: VSS is worst VCS ever. Save 1 hour/developer/day just by moving to SubVersion/Git/Mercurial...

Comment: Adding support to SubVersion to any verison of Delphi is just a little bit more than trivial, but not by much.  (http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2007/04/subversion-in-delphis-tools-menu.html)

Comment: I'll second the recommendation for VssConneXion, although haven't used it for years - it probably was around Delphi 4 timeframe :-)

I would seriously recommend moving to a different VCS  - almost anything will be better than VSS.

Comment: VssConneXion is the one thing that I like about Vss. Unfortunately we are moving to Volt, so I guess I will be left with close to nothing... :-(

Comment: This blog (http://sourceitsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/08/subversion-add-ins-for-delphi.html) has some info on Delphi and SVN integration. I'm using TortoiseSVN, as it fits with the VisualSVN for VS.